# useState to hide/show modal in react native

Tags: react-native, use-state

I want to modal my login screen anywhere in the app based on a `useState` update. I have a screen where I have a button:

```
    const [needLogin, setNeedLogin] = useState(false);

    return (
...
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                setNeedLogin(true) //This is hardcoded I'll set this value later via an  API response but for now, I just want to show the screen every time it's pressed so hard coding it to true
            }}>
                <Text>Ask Your Question</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity >
            
            {needLogin && <AuthScreen />}
...
    )
```

Now the `AuthScreen` is coded as:

```
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(true);

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Modal visible={showModal} animationType={'slide'} >
                <View style={styles.modal}>
                    <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.header}>
                                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { setShowModal(false) }}>
                                    <Image source={require('../assets/close-icon.png')} />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                            <LoginForm />
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal >
        </View >
    );
```

This logic works one time meaning, I'll click on `Ask Question` Button it'll show the `AuthScreen` and then when I'll clickk on the `close-icon` it'll close it but then if I click on  `Ask Question` again it'll not show the `AuthScreen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you AuthScreen doesn't show the second the second time is because you never set the `needLogin` state back to false. So next time you try to set it to true, it doesn't cause a re-render.

A better way of handling it will be to not maintain a separate state of AuthScreen but derive it from the props and also provide a way to update the state in parent

```
    const [needLogin, setNeedLogin] = useState(false);

    return (
    ...
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                setNeedLogin(true) //This is hardcoded I'll set this value later via an  API response but for now, I just want to show the screen every time it's pressed so hard coding it to true
            }}>
                <Text>Ask Your Question</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity >
            
            <AuthScreen open={needLogin} closeModal={() => setNeedLogin(false)}/>
       ...
    )
```

---

```
const { open, closeModal } = props;

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Modal visible={open} animationType={'slide'} >
            <View style={styles.modal}>
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                        <View style={styles.header}>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { closeModal() }}>
                                <Image source={require('../assets/close-icon.png')} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                        <LoginForm />
                </View>
            </View>
        </Modal >
    </View >
);
```